# Finding the domain in which a function is analytic with no imaginary part

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I was wondering if it is easy to see if a given expression evaluates to a real number in a given domain? Let e.g. `f(x,y,z)` be some function depending on three variables `x,y,z`. I would like to know if `f(x,y,z)` is real in some domain e.g. `x > 0, y < 0, Abs[z]<1` or e.g. `x > 0, y < 0, z < g(x,y)` (the last condition on z here just means for a given x and y, z must be smaller than the value g(x,y)).

I've tried a few things already but it seems I can't get it to work without specifying my variables from the outset (in which case I would then see if the function was real by eye). However, for many different `(x,y,z)` tuples this becomes tedious and I would like to see if it's possible to see if a function is real for all points in some domain within Mathematica.

Let `f(x,y,z) = PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z]` be a typical function I am dealing with.

I tried
`Reduce[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z] \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && y < 0 && z < 1]` but this system cannot be solved by Reduce.
I've tried also
`FunctionDomain[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z], {x, y, z}, Reals]` but it did not help either. I am using version 11.1.1.

Thanks!

Comment: `FunctionDomain[
 PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z], {x, y, z}, Reals]` returns `(x y - z == 0 && z != 0) || (z != 0 && x y + z == 0) || (z != 0 && 
   x y z + z^2 > 0 && x y z - z^2 < 0)` in version 12.1.1

Comment: @flinty I see, that's good. Unfortunately I am using version 11.1.1.

Comment: Well I can tell you from 12.1.1 that `FunctionDomain[PolyLog[n, x], x]` is `(x <= 1 && n > 1) || x < 1` so you should be able to use this for each PolyLog by replacing x->(x*y/z), or x->(-x*y/z) and n->2, then doing a reduce.

Comment: @flinty Thank you. I had tried `Reduce[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] \[Element] Reals, {x, y, z}]` but this does not work in 11.1.1. May I ask if it works on 12.1.1?

Comment: That just returns the input. What I meant was you create a function `PolyLogDomain[n_,x_] := (x <= 1 && n > 1) || x < 1` and then if `expr` is the sum of your `PolyLog`'s, you just do something like `Reduce[(And @@ ((# /. {PolyLog -> PolyLogDomain}) & /@ expr)) && ... other conditions ... ]`

Comment: You should be able to use CloudEvaluate to access M12.1.1, i.e., do: ```CloudEvaluate[
 FunctionDomain[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z], {x, y, z}, 
  Reals]]```

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, I had not heard about this `CloudEvaluate` before - is it simply a means to virtually access elements of newer versions of mathematica?